# Plugin.hh undefined symbol

Tags: ros, gazebo-plugin, gazebo-2.1

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to write a plugin for a camera. The building works fine, but when I launch the world I get the following error

```
Error [Plugin.hh:141] Failed to load plugin libvtol_camera.so: /home/mago/Development/Repository/ROS/labrob_hydro_hetcont/devel/lib/libvtol_camera.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN6gazebo17DepthCameraPluginE
```

I am using Gazebo 2.1 and ROS hydro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5094/plugin.hh-undefined-symbol/) by [Andrea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/558/andrea/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-12-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-12-04**:
This may happen when your plugin is built but not linked, could you try adding this (if you don't have it already) to your CMakeLists file: `target_link_libraries(vtol_camera ${catkin_LIBRARIES})`

**Comment by [Andrea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/558/andrea/) on 2013-12-04**:
Hi, the plugin is actually linked:
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT\_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${GAZEBO\_LIBRARIES} ${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES} )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found a solution.
I forgot to link the library in the CMakeLists.txt file

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${GAZEBO_LIBRARIES} ${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES} DepthCameraPlugin )
```

---

Originally posted by [Andrea](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/558/andrea/) with karma: 72 on 2014-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0